# RFC6979: error in reference implementation?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, random-number-generator, rfc6979

If I correctly understand [RFC 6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979), there is an error in the ref implementation [section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979#page-10).

In the step H2, RFC specification says

```
 2.  While tlen < qlen, do the following:
              V = HMAC_K(V)
              T = T || V
```

but in Java implementation in the RFC appendix, we found the comparison with *rolen*

That does not provide the same result.

For example if used with Stark curve with prime field equal to `0x0800000000000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`, *qlen* is 252 and *rolen* is 256

As consequence the loop occurs twice with *rolen*, but only once with *qlen*. it doesn't change the first k value but the subsequent k change.

The RFC code has been used now from third software.

Any thought about that?

Comment: Did you check the [errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=6979)

Comment: Yes I did, nothing related to that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The RFC specifies things in terms of *bits*. Each call to HMAC outputs `hlen` bits. `tlen` is the count of bits obtained so far; when at least `qlen` bits have been obtained, this step is finished.

The sample code is written in Java in which the elementary unit of information is the octet ("byte" in usual terminology). The supported hash functions always output a given number of bytes, and there is no fractional byte. In other words, within that code, `hlen` is always a multiple of 8. This implies that `tlen` is also a multiple of 8.

The `rolen` value is the length of `q` in octets; that is, it is equal to `qlen/8`, rounded up. This is OK in the code, since `hlen` is a multiple of 8. For instance, with a curve such that `qlen` is 252, the generation needs 252 bits of output from HMAC; but since `hlen` is a multiple of 8, you cannot get 252 bits of output without getting at least 256 bits of output. Thus, the code can keep track of things counting octets (hence, `rolen`) instead of bits. With HMAC/SHA-256, you get 32 bytes of output per HMAC call; and `rolen` is 32. Thus, one call will be enough to get `rolen` bytes, and there won't be a second one.

Comment: hmm yes I miss reading some point of the spec and search a bug in the wrong direction. I finally found what's goes wrong in the code I debug. Thanks for pointing me the truth ;)

Comment: @cslashm When this answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark-icon next to it.